# Add delay using Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Using JQuery mobile I would like to add a delay to the following code so that the css doesn't get apply until after the delay:

```
$(document).on("scrollstop", function () {
    if (!isScrolledIntoView()) {
        $("#my-div").css("bottom", "0");
    };
});
```

I have tried adding in .delay(800) but it didn't seem to work. Any ideas on how to add the delay? Thank you

Comment: Could you please clarify what changes to this code you have tried and how it didn't work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a timeout.

```
$(document).on("scrollstop", function () {
if (!isScrolledIntoView()) {
    setTimeout(function() { $("#my-div").css("bottom", "0"); }, 800);
};
```

Hope this helps.